# How to prevent new value for input when another key is not up yet?

Tags: javascript, events, input

I have the following code:

```html
<body>
  <head>
    <style>
      input[type=number] {
          height: 45px;
          width: 45px;
          font-size: 25px;
          text-align: center;
          border: 1px solid #000000;
      }
      input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
      input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function getCodeBoxElement(index) {
        return document.getElementById('codeBox' + index);
      }
      function onKeyUpEvent(index, event) {
        const eventCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
        if (getCodeBoxElement(index).value.length === 1) {
          if (index !== 4) {
            getCodeBoxElement(index+ 1).focus();
          } else {
            getCodeBoxElement(index).blur();
            // Submit code
            console.log('submit code ');
          }
        }
        if (eventCode === 8 && index !== 1) {
          getCodeBoxElement(index - 1).focus();
        }
      }
      function onFocusEvent(index) {
        for (item = 1; item < index; item++) {
          const currentElement = getCodeBoxElement(item);
          if (!currentElement.value) {
              currentElement.focus();
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
        <input id="codeBox1" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(1, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(1)"/>
        <input id="codeBox2" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(2, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(2)"/>
        <input id="codeBox3" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(3, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(3)"/>
        <input id="codeBox4" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(4, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(4)"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</body>
```

It works well, the only issue it has is when you enter numbers really fast. In that case, multiple will be inserted inside the input and all process will broke up. Something like this:

[image]

The problem is because I use `onkeyup`. If I use `onkeydown` this problem will be fixed but inconsistency happens in the sequence of indexes. Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Try replacing `onkeyup` with `oninput`

Comment: Thanks @HaoWu, I did it and the current issue fixed. But when I use `oninput`, the `backspace` button doesn't work and no digit will be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using both `oninput` and `onkeyup` event:

```html
<body>
  <head>
    <style>
      input[type=number] {
          height: 45px;
          width: 45px;
          font-size: 25px;
          text-align: center;
          border: 1px solid #000000;
      }
      input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
      input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function getCodeBoxElement(index) {
        return document.getElementById('codeBox' + index);
      }
      function onInputEvent(index, event) {
        const element = getCodeBoxElement(index);
        if (element.value.length) {
          if(element.value.length > 1) {
            element.value = element.value.substr(element.value.length - 1);
          }
          
          if (index !== 4) {
            getCodeBoxElement(index + 1).focus();
          } else {
            element.blur();
            // Submit code
            console.log('submit code ');
          }
        }
      }
      function onKeyUpEvent(index, event) {
        const eventCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
        if (eventCode === 8 && !event.target.value && index > 1) {
          event.preventDefault();
          getCodeBoxElement(index - 1).focus();
          getCodeBoxElement(index - 1).select();
        }
      }
      function onFocusEvent(index) {
        for (item = 1; item < index; item++) {
          const currentElement = getCodeBoxElement(item);
          if (!currentElement.value) {
              currentElement.focus();
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
        <input id="codeBox1" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(1, event)" oninput="onInputEvent(1, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(1)"/>
        <input id="codeBox2" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(2, event)" oninput="onInputEvent(2, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(2)"/>
        <input id="codeBox3" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(3, event)" oninput="onInputEvent(3, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(3)"/>
        <input id="codeBox4" type="number" maxlength="1" onkeyup="onKeyUpEvent(4, event)" oninput="onInputEvent(4, event)" onfocus="onFocusEvent(4)"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</body>
```

Comment: very good, thanks